# Does every function on the call stack need a return value?

Tags: java, recursion, callstack

I've been trying to understand the call stack and recursive functions but I'm stuck here.

In this code, The call stack will pile up 6 times, until a = 5,  in which case it will return 1 to the 5th call stack. But after returning to the 5th call stack, the program just goes back to main.

What about the other call stacks that don't have a return value? Doesn't every function on the call stack need to return a value?

```java
public static int func1(int a) {
   if (a == 5) {
       return 1;
   }
   return func1(a + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   func1(0);

}
```

Edit: I've heard it shouldn't go back to main after the 5th call stack and it should go back down the call stack 1 at a time, but my code goes back to main right after this step which as you can see, is on the 5th call stack  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDO2J.png

Comment: It doesn't go all the way back up the stack.  It goes up one, then the next, then the next, until it reaches main.

Comment: "Doesn't every function on the call stack need to return a value?" No, void methods don't return a value.

Answer (score 1):

> What about the other call stacks that don't have a return value? Doesn't every function on the call stack need to return a value?

Actually no, as stated by @Sweeper, void methods, for istance, don't return a *value*. If Java behaves similarly to Python, functions will return a null type by default.

But the call stack executes normally in your case. The return value is just processed by the function call. It executes like this:

1. main() calls func(0)
2. func(0) calls func(0+1)
3. func(0+1) calls func(0+1+1)
4. func(0+1+1) calls func(0+1+1+1)
5. func(0+1+1+1) calls func(0+1+1+1+1)
6. func(0+1+1+1+1) calls func(0+1+1+1+1+1)
7. func(0+1+1+1+1+1) returns 5 to func(0+1+1+1+1)
8. func(0+1+1+1+1) returns 5 to func(0+1+1+1)
9. func(0+1+1+1) returns 5 to func(0+1+1)
10. func(0+1+1) returns 5 to func(0+1)
11. func(0+1) returns 5 func(0)
12. func(0) returns 5 to main()
13. main() returns 5

Comment: When I debugged it in Java, it just went back the main function after step 7

Comment: Because the rest of it is implicit. I just put it there for the sake of completeness =D.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't every function on the call stack need to return a value?

They all need to return.  (Void functions don't need to return a value, everything else does.)

> But after returning to the 5th call stack, the program just goes back to main.

No.  Your code returns from one call, then the next, then the next, until it reaches main.

Comment: When I debugged it in Java using IntelliJ, it just went back the main function after I returned from the 5th call stack.

Comment: Sure, but the debugger is designed to help you debug, not to go through the gritty details of how the JVM works.

Comment: @compsci3289294 How _exactly_ did you "return"? There are usually a number of "step" instructions.

Answer (score 0):

> But after returning to the 5th call stack, the program just goes back to main.

This is incorrect. The stack *unwinds*: The 5th call returns a value to the 4th call, which returns a value to the 3rd call, until all of the stack frames are resolved and the final result is returned to `main`.

Comment: The last paragraph is a bit inaccurate. The addition is done on the argument to the recursive call, not on its return value.

Comment: @marstran That's what I get for Stacking before caffeine.

Comment: chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic Haha :)